# Find html element add id to parent

Tags: jquery, parent, closest

I'm having an issue here, I have a piece of code that works great.

```
 $('td img[src="/images/nav/prev_dim.gif"]').parent().closest("table").attr('class','robsid');
```

does just what I want it to do. however the path of the image changes after.gif like this here,

/images/nav/prev.gif?v=2015.2.0

how do I ignore the ?v= and just focus on finding the image name so when it changes for example pagination. it will ignore after.gif

Answer (score 3):

Use [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('td img[src^="/images/nav/prev.gif"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquery "starts with" selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) like this:

```
$('td img[src^="/images/nav/prev_dim.gif"]').parent().closest("table").attr('class','robsid');
```

But personally, I would suggest putting a class on the `img` instead.

Comment: our answers were almost simultaneous. 2015-10-15 03:38:16Z vs 2015-10-15 03:37:37Z - 21 seconds aparat

Comment: (y) you lost the race though :D chill

Answer (score 0):

can u try this

```
$('td img[src^="/images/nav/prev_dim.gif"]').parent().closest("table").attr('class','robsid');
```

Comment: figured it out, thank you very much dude you guys rock!